# How does systemd ask units to reload configuration?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I was reading the manpage for `systemctl reload` and found this sentence about `reload`.

```
reload PATTERN...
    Asks all units listed on the command line to reload their
    configuration.
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html

How does systemd do that? What API does systemd use to ask a unit to reload its configuration?

I also found `reload-or-restart`.

```
 reload-or-restart PATTERN...
     Reload one or more units if they support it. If not, restart them
     instead.
```

How does systemd *know* if the unit supports reload?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what the man page `systemd.service` says about reloading:

```
       ExecReload=
           Commands to execute to trigger a configuration reload in the 
           service. This argument takes multiple command lines, following
           the same scheme as described for ExecStart= above. Use of
           this setting is optional. Specifier and environment variable
           substitution is supported here following the same scheme as
           for ExecStart=.

           One additional, special environment variable is set: if known,
           $MAINPID is set to the main process of the daemon, and may
           be used for command lines like the following:

               /bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

           Note however that reloading a daemon by sending a signal
           (as with the example line above) is usually not a good
           choice, because this is an asynchronous operation and hence
           not suitable to order reloads of multiple services against
           each other. It is strongly recommended to set ExecReload=
           to a command that not only triggers a configuration reload
           of the daemon, but also synchronously waits for it to complete.
```

(The only way to know that `systemd.service` is the correct man page to look in was to Google for `ExecReload`, a string I guessed after digging through Systemd's source code.)